# Jquery how to bind click event on dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, bind

I tried the  below code but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.pg_previous,.pg_next', function () {
            jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({});
            alert('ddsda');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Jquery  1.9.1

Comment: This fiddle works without the `lazy` call, maybe look there, or move the alert ahead of the `lazy` call. http://jsfiddle.net/5SyS3/

Comment: @JasonP this is cancelling the event :(  "return false;"

Comment: Try replacing `return false;` with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: +1 for using body as selector instead of class selector (for dynamically created element)

Comment: Here's a detailed article on how to bind click event for dynamic element http://goo.gl/zlEbnv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.pg_previous,.pg_next', function () {
        jQuery("img.lazy").lazy({});
        alert('ddsda');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This did it for me! Thank you! Attaching the click event to the parent element and selecting its children is the most efficient way.

Comment: both are equivalent, but for this particular version of jQuery I often found the long version doesn't work, and the shortcut do.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `DOM ready` handler

Encase your code inside the ready handler and should work fine unless you have any errors showing up in our console.

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: ok i believe another code cancels default action so it cancels binded action too thanks