# jQuery - Event not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm setting a click event on an anchor to set a value to a button (initially, the button has a -1 value, that can't be submitted) that later will submit an Ajax call. The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't; I just don't understand why.

**JS**:

```
$(".events-list a").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('event-id');
    $(".edit-occurrence-button").val(id);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="modal-edit-occurrence-form" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-edit-occurrence-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="modal-edit-occurrence-label">Editar ocorrência</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Some input fields here -->
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="modal-edit-occurrence-submit" class="btn btn-info">Editar</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal hide fade" id="events-modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Ocorrência</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="height: 600px;">
        <!-- Some content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-info edit-occurrence-button" value="-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Editar</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS**: The `.events-list a` is an anchor generated by BootstrapCalendar dynamically (http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/), that has this format:

```
<div class="events-list" data-cal-start="1386126000000" data-cal-end="1386212400000">
    <a href="mylink.php?id=44" data-event-id="44" data-event-class="event-a" class="pull-left event event-a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="a"></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I found out why it doesn't work sometimes. It deppends on what element is triggering the event. On Bootstrap Calendar, we have 3 ways of openning the calendar event (clicking the event on the calendar, clicking the event after opening the day's events, clicking on the last events). The problem is only when I try to click on the event after opening the day's events, because it is generated dynamically. How can I fix it?

Comment: the value attribute is not what you want.

Comment: Use `$(".edit-occurrence-button").val(id)` instead of setting the `value` attribute. But show your html as well and how to replicate the issue.

Comment: Are you saying the event doesn't fire, or something else? I would suggest provide full code to replicate the issue. Preferably with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: does your button creates before domready? or after some actions ?

Comment: Also, you might want to prevent the default anchor behaviour

Comment: sometimes not working mean may be `callback issue` or logical issue.  What the remaining part of `(a).click(function(){});` does?

Comment: Have you looked for console errors and looked at the network monitor? (F12 on Chrome)

Comment: @PSL I already tried with `.val(id)` instead of `.attr("value", id)`, but the result was the same.

Comment: @ErmSo No console errors here.

Comment: @LucasHarada We cannot help you with your incomplete question. You need to provide enough code to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Murali The `.click(function(){});` is only the written code. As I wrote before, this is only for changing a button's value for a later submit form.

Comment: try preventing default event using `$(".events-list a").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();...}`

Comment: @LucasHarada, please check my answer for HTML structure detail. Please add your HTML code, may be help us

Comment: @PSL There is the HTML part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that jquery can't see the element and attach a event handler.

Try using the [jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler

```
$("##static_parent##").on('click' , '.events-list a', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('event-id');
    $(".edit-occurrence-button").val(id);
});
```

Replace ##static_parent## with a parent element of your target element that's rendered in the page on load. (if you can't find any use 'body').

This might be [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558167/jquery-how-to-bind-click-event-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Probably something to do with load order - if your html is generated before your event handler is interpreted by the browser - it probably works, if the html is not yet generated it doesn't. Try my solution and it should work every time.

Comment: I edited the question. I was wrong about the element being generated before the DOM ready.

Answer (score 1):

Try `preventing default event` for `<a>` also with some code refactoring

```
$(".events-list a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('event-id');
    $(".edit-occurrence-button").val(id);
});
```

Assuming the HTML looks like below

```
 <input type="submit" class="edit-occurrence-button" value="1" />

<ul class="event-list">
<li><a href="#">Event</a>
</a>
```

Comment: I posted the HTML part. I tried to adapt your code, but it doesn't work too. The `e.preventDefault();` didn't solve.

Comment: @LucasHarada What is the issue exactly. By doesn't work you mean it doesn't set the value? Here is a bootstrap template see if you can place the code here and replicate your issue http://jsfiddle.net/uejym/

Comment: Exactly, sometimes it works nice, changes the value from -1 to 44, on the example; sometimes, doesn't do anything, the value -1 keeps unchanged.