# Apply jQueryUI Resizable widget to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

## This question is not about event delegation

I would like to apply the jQuery resizable widget to a series of `div` tags that could potentially be created dynamically.

Is there a way to use something that **behaves** like event delegation to dynamically add the jQuery `resizable` widget to new elements?

Here's the example (notice how the newly created green elements cannot be resized):

```js
$(function() {
  var cols = $("#cols").children(".col");

  cols.resizable({
    maxHeight: 20,
    minHeight: 20,
    distance: 5,
    handles: 'e',
    start: function() {
      console.log("I've started!");
    },
    stop: function() {
      console.log("I've stopped!");
    }
  });

  $("#addNew").on("click", function() {

    cols.filter(":last").after('<div class="col new">' + parseInt(cols.length + 1) + '</div>');

    cols = $("#cols").children(".col");

  });
});
```

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.col.new {
  background: #0f0;
}
button {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="cols">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
<button id="addNew">Add</button>
```

**EDIT:** I am not asking about **event delegation**, I'm asking if there is a way to delegate the resizable widget to dynamically add it to newly created elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery how to bind click event on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558167/jquery-how-to-bind-click-event-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @MelanciaUK I can't see how these are the same? I'm asking how you could delegate a resizable widget which isn't an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialize `col.resizable();` once new element added.
Please check below working code:

```js
$(function() {
  var cols = $(".col");


  cols.resizable({
    maxHeight: 20,
    minHeight: 20,
    distance: 5,
    handles: 'e',
    start: function() {
      console.log("I've started!");
    },
    stop: function() {
      console.log("I've stopped!");
    }


  });


  $("#addNew").on("click", function() {

    cols.filter(":last").after('<div class="col new">' + parseInt(cols.length + 1) + '</div>');
    
    cols = $(".col");
    cols.resizable({maxHeight: 20,
    minHeight: 20,
    distance: 5,
    handles: 'e'});

  });

});
```

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.col.new {
  background: #0f0;
}
button {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="cols">

  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>

</div>
<button id="addNew">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was trying to avoid doing it this way due to repeated code.

Comment: for the dynamic created element you must need to reinitilize the function resizable() without that it will not work

Comment: I take it reinitializing resizable() will not create duplicated instances?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post, But still I felt I could post a better answer for future reference, Since in your comments you had mentioned about code reuse and not applying the plugin to elements multiple times this solution should overcome those issues.

```js
$(function() {
 
  ApplyResizablePluginToCol($(".col"));  // cal the function by passing all the elements to which the plugin must be applied to

  $("#addNew").on("click", function() {

    $(".col:last").after('<div class="col new">' + parseInt( $(".col").length + 1) + '</div>');       
    ApplyResizablePluginToCol($(".col:last"));// take the last element, ie the element that is created just now

  });

  function ApplyResizablePluginToCol(elements){ //reusable function
    
    elements.resizable({
     maxHeight: 20,
     minHeight: 20,
     distance: 5,
     handles: 'e',
     start: function() {
       console.log("I've started!");
     },
     stop: function() {
       console.log("I've stopped!");
     }
   });
 }  
  
});
```

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.col.new {
  background: #0f0;
}
button {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="cols">

  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>

</div>
<button id="addNew">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's working for me

```
$("#cols").on('mouseenter',cols,function(){
    cols.resizable({
    maxHeight: 20,
    minHeight: 20,
    distance: 5,
    handles: 'e',
    start: function() {
       console.log("I've started!");
    },
    stop: function() {
       console.log("I've stopped!");
    }

    });

});
```