# How to drop the draggable div when onclick on it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, onclick, clone

I have an element which needs to drop into droppable(`Jquery UI droppable`) div while drag and drop(works perfect), but i need to drop the same element while onclick on it.

**Reason why i need the above said functionality:** The code gets repeat while used separate code to clone and append the element into droppable div when onclick. I need to use same code for both. How to pass the onclicked element (draggable element) into drop function.?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var cloned_element;

    $("#draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: true
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable(
    { 
        drop: function(event, ui) 
        {
            cloned_element = $(ui.helper).clone();
            ui.helper.remove();
            cloned_element.appendTo(this);

            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped!");
        }
    });

    $('#draggable').on('click',function()
    {
        $(this).trigger("drop", $('#droppable'));
    });    
});
```

Sample code in [Jsfiddle..!](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/eLzse0ym/)

Comment: can you elaborate. So you dont want drag and drop functionality ? On click of draggable ,, it should drop into droppable ?

Comment: @ Yo Yo.. I used both drag and drop, and also onclick to append element into droppable div. I used the dropped div to make resize, rotate, like various functionalities inside the droppable div, so these codes get repeat when i used seperate function for onclick.

Comment: ok see my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can trigger drag drop functionality on click .
But you can do something like this

```
 $('#draggable').on('click',function()
        {
            cloned_element = $("#draggable").clone();
            cloned_element.attr("id","").css("position","absolute");
            cloned_element.find("p").html("Dropped!");
            cloned_element.appendTo("#droppable");
        });
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eLzse0ym/2/)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eLzse0ym/4/) for your second query.  - how to assign resizable() to all dropped elements.

Comment: @ Yo Yo... I don't need this separate function. I have this code. when i use Jquery UI resizable or other functionality to the cloned element, i need to repeat the code for both drag-dropped and onclicked functions. Can you understand what i need..? Please help me

Comment: @ Yo Yo..  or any other way to pass the onclicked element into drop function..?

Comment: @ArunValaven : your question was **How to drop the draggable div when onclick on it?** which I answered. ok i will try to fix this too

Comment: @ Yo Yo..  Can you prescribe me how i can change the question for better understanding..? Thanks for your future effort to solve my issue.

Comment: @ArunValaven : what you can do is assign a same class (say `.dropped_box`) to all the dropped elements (created by click or drag) and assign that class with any JQuery-UI functionality - `.resizable();` or whatever . It should work

Comment: @ArunValaven : see my Updated answer for second demo. Your solution is there

Comment: @ Yo Yo.. Yes.... That code also i have.. I used the way used the resizable() function. But i your demo itself shows my problem(code repetation, used resizable for both function).. Thanks..

Comment: @ArunValaven : see both are different events . you need assign the functionalities to both the events. , or call a function in both events , which will contain all the declared jquery functionalities you want to add

Comment: @ Yo Yo.. So in my code which is best to use.? Assign same class name for all drag-drop and onclick elements Or calling a same function in both functions..?

Comment: see if are adding a class then you need to handle the delegate event handler too . Better make a separate function declare all functionalities in it .. run that function AFTER every time you add the element

Comment: @ Yo Yo.. Can you able to give a demo to implement this function using delegate event handler..? just by simply assigning resizable functionality for both function.

Comment: @ArunValaven .. Yes  , see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512442/apply-jqueryui-resizable-widget-to-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @ Yo Yo.. ok Thanks