# Detect list item index with custom list made of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a dynamically built list such as :

```html
<ul id="shortcuts">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo</button><button>-</button></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo</button><button>-</button></li>
  <!-- possibly many others lis -->
</ul>
```

So in order to use only one click event listener, I am trying to attach click event to the list and get the list item index that initially spread the event. Any of my attempts succeed so far.

I can get something out of this :

```js
$("#shorcuts").click ( function(evt) {
   alert( evt.target );
});
```

But I can't get to the "li" html element nor its "index" within the list. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attache event to `li` like below

```js
$(function(){
  $('#shortcuts').on('click','li',function(){
    alert($(this).index());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shortcuts">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo</button><button>-</button></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo</button><button>-</button></li>
  <!-- possibly many others lis -->
</ul>
```

Here click event will delegate to all `li`s inside `shortcuts`  and you can get the index of clicked `li` using `.index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get index with [JQuery - `index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

```
$('selector').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bCTAh/171/)

**OR**

```
$("#shorcuts").on("click","li", function(evt) {
    alert($(this).index());
}
```

Look at here for more options [SO - Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545283/get-index-of-clicked-element-in-collection-with-jquery)

[event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

[bind-click-event-on-dynamically-created-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558167/jquery-how-to-bind-click-event-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Looks like it's working if the list items are previously created. If they are later added, the event listener is not active for these new elements.

Comment: @Loic You have to attach click event dynamically when you are creating elements. I have added links to the answer. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Still can't get to work but the links are instructive.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#shortcuts li',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shortcuts">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo1</button><button>-</button></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="false"/><button>foo2</button><button>-</button></li>
  <!-- possibly many others lis -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. ….index() seems to always return 0. on(…) doesn't seem to throw the alert.

Comment: on() doesn't seem to throw the alert?