# Dynamically created buttons won't fire when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating buttons based on what a user enters into an input box. However, the function i have linked to the dynamically created buttons won't fire when pressed.

```
function btnCreate() {
num++;
userBtn = $("<button>")
userBtn
    .addClass("btn search-term-btn dynamicElement")
    .appendTo($(".btn-holder"))
    .text(topics)
    .attr("data-name", topics);
usedTopics.push(topics + num);
topics = [];
console.log(num);
};

$(".search-term-btn").on("click", ".dynamicElement", function () {
// takes the name of the button 
searchValue = $(".search-term").attr("data-name");
console.log(searchValue);
})
```

The class is correct, ive checked with the inspector. I just can't seem to figure out why it's unresponsive

Comment: Are you creating buttons inside buttons?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: No, im using the input submit button to call a function that causes the buttons to be made

Comment: Then you probably submit the form, and your server sends a new page as a response. As Quentin said, please post a reproducable example, so that we don't have to speculate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to bind click event on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558167/jquery-how-to-bind-click-event-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: You append the newly created buttons to `.btn-holder`. does that element also have the `.search-term-btn` class? Is it a child of `.search-term-btn` Or is it a different element with a handler not shown? As written, it comes across as if the buttons aren't appended to the container that has the delegated event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the click event on DOM.

```
$(document).on("click", ".search-term-btn .dynamicElement", function () {
   console.log(this)
});
```

Comment: oh my god, that solved it.. thank you. Ive been looking back to some activity  works and none of them have used this. But this seems to have fixed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
while you are creating the buttons, you can add the onclick function there..
like userBtn = $("<button onlcikc="somefunction(this)">")
```

OR
you can use on function which is

```
$('body').on(  "click",".dynamicElement", function() {  
  //your code
});
```

Comment: delegate has been deprecated in jquery 3, you should use .on() instead

Comment: Yes like
 $(document).on("click", 'p',function() {  
  $(this ).after( "<p>Click me for another paragraph.</p>" );  
});

Comment: Still second one won't work as .dynamicElement is created after the document is loaded.